# Dbus: How can I monitor process?

Tags: linux, login, session, dbus

I'm new with Dbus and I'm curious if there is any way to monitor process and see if this process receives any Dbus messages. (I'm working on some project and want to know if Xserver receives any Dbus messages when logging out). Thank you very much.

Comment: Which dbus version do you have?

Comment: D-Bus Message Bus Daemon 1.6.18

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingDBus) WIKI article:

There are two buses commonly used: the `session bus` and the `system bus`. Either may be used by any application, depending on what it is doing.

- To monitor the session bus:  `dbus-monitor`
- To monitor the system bus:

create a file `/etc/dbus-1/system-local.conf`, with these contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
"-//freedesktop//DTD D-Bus Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
"http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
    <policy user="root">
        <allow eavesdrop="true"/>
        <allow eavesdrop="true" send_destination="*"/>
    </policy>
</busconfig>
```

Reboot your machine to pick up the configuration changes. Simply reloading the DBus server configuration is not sufficient. For further info see this bug.

Now run dbus-monitor as root. You should be able to see all signals, method calls, and method replies.

```
sudo dbus-monitor --system
```

When done debugging, it is wise to remove the policy snippet:

```
sudo rm /etc/dbus-1/system-local.conf
```

Comment: I've seen that article but how can I parse the messages by only knowing destination process name?

Comment: The 'eavesdrop' instructions are fortunately no longer needed with dbus 1.10 (they used to cause some weird side-effects in the past).